# How to use path having more than 128 character in 'xp_cmdshell' DIR command

Tags: sql-server, xp-cmdshell

I am trying to get list of files in a directory using SQL Server path having more than 128 character. It isn't working.

```
DECLARE 
@FilePath varchar(256)='D:\...',--Path with a length more than 128 char

@SourceFiles varchar(100)='Test123456789*.txt',
@Query varchar(1000)

If Object_Id('tempdb.dbo.#FirstTable') Is NULL
    CREATE TABLE #FirstTable (Name varchar(256))

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET @Query ='master.dbo.xp_cmdshell "dir '+ @FilePath + '\' + @SourceFiles +' /b"'

INSERT #FirstTable exec (@Query)
select * from #FirstTable

truncate table #FirstTable
```

This gives the following error:

> The identifier that starts with 'dir D:....' is too long. Maximum length is 128.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to this issue is the wording of the error message (emphasis added):

> The **identifier** that starts with

An *identifier* is a name of an object or item within SQL Server, *not* a literal string. For example, `master`, `dbo`, and `xp_cmdshell` are all identifiers.

So, you have two options:

### Simple fix (but not the best practice)

The issue being with identifiers is a clue that points to the `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON` line. Just changing the `ON` to be `OFF` will allow this to work. However, you will get an error if there is a space in your path and/or filename pattern (e.g. **C:\Program Files (x86)\** ).

### Best practice fix (that is still pretty easy)

Use single-quotes instead of double-quotes around the shell command. And since you are creating the command in Dynamic SQL, it needs to be two single-quotes in both instances. So, `...xp_cmdshell ''dir ... /b''...`

If there are any spaces in the path itself, then you need double-quotes around the path: `...xp_cmdshell ''dir "..." /b''...`

Hence, the full syntax would be:

```sql
SET @Query ='master.dbo.xp_cmdshell ''dir "'+ @FilePath + '\' + @SourceFiles +'" /b''';
```

Putting it into the the full original code, along with a long path name and an extra `SELECT` and `PRINT` to see what is going on, you get:

```sql
DECLARE @FilePath varchar(256)='C:\Users\Solomon\AppData\Local\Microsoft\HelpViewer2.0\TableOfContentsFilterCache\VisualStudio11\en-US',--Path with a length more than 128 char
@SourceFiles varchar(100)='this_is_a_long_file_name.*',
@Query varchar(1000);

IF (OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb.dbo.#FirstTable') IS NULL)
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #FirstTable (Name VARCHAR(256));
END;

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
SET @Query ='master.dbo.xp_cmdshell ''dir "'+ @FilePath + '\' + @SourceFiles +'" /b''';

SELECT LEN(@FilePath + '\' + @SourceFiles);
PRINT @Query;

INSERT #FirstTable EXEC(@Query);
  SELECT * FROM #FirstTable;
```

Running that gets no errors. The value of `@Query`, shown in the "Messages" tab, renders as:

```sql
master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'dir "C:\Users\Solomon\AppData\Local\Microsoft\HelpViewer2.0\TableOfContentsFilterCache\VisualStudio11\en-US\this_is_a_long_file_name.*" /b'
```

Now, prior to the changes that I suggested, there was an error. The output from the original code (with the same test values) is:

"Results" tab:

```
129
```

"Messages" tab:

> master.dbo.xp_cmdshell "dir C:\Users\Solomon\AppData\Local\Microsoft\HelpViewer2.0\TableOfContentsFilterCache\VisualStudio11\en-US\this_is_a_long_file_name.* /b"
>
> Msg 103, Level 15, State 4, Line 1
>   The identifier that starts with 'dir C:\Users\Solomon\AppData\Local\Microsoft\HelpViewer2.0\TableOfContentsFilterCache\VisualStudio11\en-US\this_is_a_long_file_n' is too long. Maximum length is 128.

Comment: If we use single-quotes than it will not considere as one command in xp_cmdshell so, it will show error as "The system cannot find the path specified."

Comment: @Husen The xp_cmdshell stored procedure expects a VARCHAR or NVARCHAR parameter. That is why you need to put single quotes around the complete `DIR` command. Since you are formatting this command within a VARCHAR itself, you need to double those, i.e. put two single quotes to get one single quote in the final string.

Comment: I have tried all the permutations and combinations in this. Please check in a local environment and then suggest syntax.

Comment: @Husen I had provided that syntax, but in case it was difficult to put it back into the code, I have updated my answer with the full script. I also added a full explanation of the error and a second (though not as good) option.

Comment: @srutzky Read it... I wonder why the OP thought he needed an explicit `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` set to `ON`. I don't think it's necessary for what he wants to do.

Comment: @TT. My guess is that it was an attempt to get the double-quotes to work.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the fun of it I created a directory `C:\Temp\Temporary folder with an unecessarily long name just to be an example etc etc\Temporary folder with an unecessarily long name just to be an example etc etc` (163 characters) and placed a bunch of `test*.txt` files in it.

The following script does not have the problems you are describing.

```
DECLARE @file_path NVARCHAR(256)='C:\Temp\Temporary folder with an unecessarily long name just to be an example etc etc\Temporary folder with an unecessarily long name just to be an example etc etc';
PRINT LEN(@file_path); -- prints 163
DECLARE @src_files NVARCHAR(100)='test*.txt';
DECLARE @dir_cmd NVARCHAR(4000)='DIR "'+@file_path+'\'+@src_files+'" /b';

CREATE TABLE #dir_table(name NVARCHAR(256));
INSERT INTO #dir_table(name) EXEC xp_cmdshell @dir_cmd;

SELECT*FROM #dir_table; -- result is a bunch of test*.txt files
DROP TABLE #dir_table;
```